# MySQL Finding Most Similar Combination Of 3 Columns/Values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am attempting to make a very basic image matching script in PHP, what I am doing is grabbing the RGB averages of each channel, and then matching these 3 values against results stored in the database.

So I have all this done, and the results setup in the DB, I am just having trouble writing my final query now to check the computed results from my active image against the stored results.

SO the DB table looks like this right now:

```
id (primary index)    
name
image
rval (fulltext index)
gval (fulltext index)
bval (fulltext index)
```

Originally, I had the color average fields set as INTs, but changed them now to mess around with fulltext searches... I'm not really sure how to go about this :P

Anyway, so my query should be something like this:

```
$rval = '100';
$gval = '109';
$bval = '114';

"SELECT name, image FROM table WHERE rval LIKE '$rval' AND gval LIKE '$gval' AND bval LIKE '$bval' LIMIT 3"
```

And then ideally it would return back the 3 most similar combinations.

SQL wizards, if you have any suggestions I would love to hear/SEE them! Thanks in advance everyone :)

Comment: post a few examples that return from: "SELECT * FROM table" - cause it's not very clear what are the possible values

Answer (score 0):

You could try searching between a range of values for each rgb value.

```
$rval = '100';
$gval = '109';
$bval = '114';

"SELECT name, image FROM table WHERE rval BETWEEN ".$rval-10." AND ".$rval+10.....etc.
```

Of course, I don't think this would give the three most right combinations, you would have to work your way out until you got three matches. -1, -2, -3 spots away, something like that.

Comment: yeah, that's a lot of queries in my case! :) thanks for the idea though